# Why does Signal app not have network access?

Tags: internet, signal-private-messenger

I am trying to install Signal on a phone (Android 8). I just need this installed for verifying/linking my actual Signal desktop app. When I enter my number, the app tells me it has no permission/access to the network. The error message translated to English is:

> Unable to connect to service. Please check your network connection and try again.

I have checked both the internet connection and the mobile connection, they work fine. I gave Signal all the permissions it asked for.

Is there anything else I can do?

Edit: It seems to work (for a while) when the Signal app is updated. I managed to relink my Signal Desktop app to the smartphone app after the smartphone app had updated. Then, after some days, the Desktop app unlinked itself again. I installed the smartphone app again via Google Play and was able to relink again.
It's not logic and stable, but it can be a workaround.

Comment: There are some reported issues on its GitHub: [Signal App - Android ICS - Unable to Connect - Network Error - Registration Fail](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/issues/8205) (and its linked issues), [Unable to register: cannot connect to server](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android/issues/8475). Looks like the issue is related to Google Play Services.