# Almost all things equal, WhatsApp is unable to connect on Android 12 vs Android 10

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, internet

Two Samsung phones, one running an Android 10, another Android 12. Same firewall configuration, same router config, same positive WiFi internet connectivity for other apps on both phones. WhatsApp connects on Android 10 but does not connect on Android 12.

Tried Android 10 on the phone with Android 12 and WhatsApp runs fine on Android 10 then on that phone.

What happened with Android 12 to prevent WhatsApp connectivity? How to fix this?

UPDATE: "Almost" all things equal. I forgot that when I compiled Android 12 I edited some SELinux capabilities/permissions in Android 12 source code for Netd daemon (in netd.rc config file), such as restricting unrestricted rootkit-like elevated SELinux access, ability to change file ownership, etc. This was not possible in Android 10. So there's that difference.

Comment: One difference might be that Android 12 uses by default secure DNS. See Android network settings. In which country do you live respectively which internet provider do you use (some countries or provider may block certain DNS resolvers because they can be used to bypass blocked sites)?

Comment: Could you clarify on "unable to connect"? Did you mean that WhatsApp cannot connect to the internet at all, or when it is only in the background? Is there any specific error message? I have a Galaxy M12 on Android 12 and upgraded to Android 13, and WhatsApp doesn't have any connection problems though.

Comment: WhatsApp won't let me register the phone number so I can log in to the WhatsApp account. When you open the app for the first time you enter you phone and it tries to communicate with WhatsApp servers to send a text message with the code usually. In this case, you enter the number and it pops a message saying cannot connect to servers, check status or something like that.

Comment: I have Private DNS set to Off. I don't think this has to do with it.

Comment: I have a strict firewall on both Android 10 and 12. Only letting through ports 80 and 443 for TCP. But this shouldn't matter because everything works on Android 10. So strange.

Comment: I also have self-compiled Android 12 with some SELinux restrictions. Android 10 did not have any SELinux edits. I took out the all the rootkit-like SELinux permissions for the Netd daemon (in netd.rc configuration), like permissions to have unrestricted elevated SELinux access, change file ownership, etc. Could it be that WhatsApp trying to use those elevated rootkit capabilities?

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but recently there was [a similar question about a connection issue with the Signal app on registration](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250917/44325), and seems it was caused by Google Play Services.